# Importing libraries in AWS Lambda function code from S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deep-learning, aws-lambda

I have to deploy a Deep Learning model on AWS Lambda which does object detection. It is triggered on addition of image in the S3 bucket.
The issue that I'm facing is that the Lambda function code uses a lot of libraries like Tensorflow, PIL, Numpy, Matplotlib, etc. and if I try adding all of them in the function code or as layers, it exceeds the 250 MB size limit. 
Is there any way I can deploy the libraries zip file on S3 bucket and use them from there in the function code (written in Python 3.6) instead of directly having them as a part of the code?
I can also try some entirely different approach for this.

Comment: How about split packages into multiple lambda layers, a lambda can have up to 5 layers?

Comment: @SangminKim The total limit of 250 MB includes the function code size along with the layers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I changed my approach from using Lambda to using EC2.
I deployed the whole code with libraries on an EC2 instance and then triggered it using Lambda. On EC2, it can also be deployed on Apache server to change port mapping.

Comment: This is not needed anymore. AWS Lambda and ML models of all kind are now quite easy to use, see here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/using-container-images-to-run-tensorflow-models-in-aws-lambda/

Comment: @janbauer I solved my problem long back, thank you for this though! :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like Amazon SageMaker would be a better choice for your task.

You can create a model and host it on an endpoint all via SageMaker. The use a lambda function triggered by your s3 upload to pass the image to your SageMaker endpoint and process the result.

> Amazon SageMaker is a fully managed service that provides every developer and data scientist with the ability to build, train, and deploy machine learning (ML) models quickly. SageMaker removes the heavy lifting from each step of the machine learning process to make it easier to develop high quality models.

https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/

Answer (score 1):

Try out [pre-compiled packs](https://github.com/ryfeus/lambda-packs#tensorflow) for Tensorflow, they are about 50MB, you probably would have enough space for the rest of modules you need. And in general, check the [AWS recommendations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-deep-learning-models-with-aws-lambda-and-tensorflow/) on deep learning architecture approaches.

Comment: The pre-compiled packs are for Python 2.7 and don't provide a suitable runtime for Python 3.x